# Drop Down menu Display Issue jQuery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have Two Drop Down Menus. One is main Menu And Other is SubMenu.

```
<div id="menu">
    <select data-native-menu="false" id="mainMenu" name="select-choice-0">
        </select> <select data-native-menu="false" id="subMenu" name=
        "select-choice-1">
        </select>
</div><!--End of menu-->
```

I have Populated the main Menu With Array Data but Iam not Able to Show the Submenu with Respective Main menu data. what i have tried is

```
function setSubMenu(indexPos) {
    var selectedMenuArray = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < sortedArray[menuKeys[indexPos]].length; i++) {
            selectedMenuArray.push(sortedArray[menuKeys[indexPos]][i]);
        }
        //creating submenu
        var subMenuId = $('#subMenu');
        var subCatHtml = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < selectedMenuArray.length; i++) {
            console.log(selectedMenuArray[i]['subcategory']);
            subCatHtml += '<option>' + selectedMenuArray[i]['subcategory'] + '</option>';
        }

    subMenuId.html(subCatHtml);
    subMenuId.selectmenu();
    subMenuId.selectmenu('refresh');
}
```

Here iam passing the Index position of Main Menu Item. Then iam pushing the Respective items to SelectedMenuArray to Display them in SubMenu.
here my problem is iam unable to display the Submenu items.

Comment: Can post a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
submenuID.trigger('create');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 subMenuId.html(subCatHtml).trigger('create');
 subMenuId.html(subCatHtml).selectmenu('refresh', true);
```